# As a provider of deep synthesis services hosted in the US but have customers based in China, must I make sure that my service contains watermarks?

Tags: united-states, internet, service, china, artificial-intelligence

I read on https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2022/12/china-bans-ai-generated-media-without-watermarks/;

> Providers of deep synthesis services shall add signs that do not affect the use of information content generated or edited using their services. Services that provide functions such as intelligent dialogue, synthesized human voice, human face generation, and immersive realistic scenes that generate or significantly change information content, shall be marked prominently to avoid public confusion or misidentification.
>
> It is required that no organization or individual shall use technical means to delete, tamper with, or conceal relevant marks.

If I am a provider of deep synthesis services that are hosted in the US but have some customers based in China, must I make sure that my service contains watermarks?

Comment: Any answers or comments are welcome.

Comment: I am still interested in this question.